# Display Toast message on lock screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-toast

Toast message on lock screen is working fine on Samsung Galaxy S4 (OS 4.4.2).
But same code is not working on other devices with different OS version (e.g. 5.0)
Toast message is not displayed when device is locked.

Is there any way to display toast message on locked screen ?

Below is my class :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    if (isLockScreen(this)) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please unlock.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: please write here the permissions which you are allowed in manifest.xml

Comment: '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />'

Answer (score 0):

Ok , permissions looking fine , just place the code before Toast.show

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
wl.acquire(15000);
```

Comment: Hello Abe, i used above code befor toast but still toast is not displaying.

Comment: share your class where you place toast and want to display

Comment: I have edited my question and added the piece of code.

Comment: your code will work when your activity will run ...for your requirement you need to put this code in receiver ! meanwhile at the moment Toast will appear only when activity on front ..please how to use receiver

Comment: Hello Abe , is there any way to show toast without bringing the activity on top of lock screen (which is happening in galaxy s4 , os 4.4.2).

i am bale to bring the activity on top of lock screen by using  FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED , but my requirement is not to bring activity on top but just to show the toast message on lock screen which will ask user to unlock the screen and when he will unlock the above activity will remain display which i mentioned in my question. 

i am facing this issue after 4.4.2 OS device.

Comment: send me the code and requirement I will fix your issue